# How to write a program with commands?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, file

I would like to write a program that will handle commands like

add: And asks for your first name, surname, age
list: List the people in a directory
remove: removes
detail: Displays the details of the person
open: opens a file. (from json and xml)
save: save the file (in json and xml)

I am at this stage so far

and my question is as follows ....
the code below is File and it doesn't have options like remove or detail, add

I need hints such as what method, link, etc.
I will be grateful

```
string path2 = @"logowanie6.txt";
        Console.WriteLine("Hej! Przedstaw się. Twoje dane będą zapisane w pliku o nazwie logowanie6.txt");

        if (!File.Exists(path2))
        {

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path2))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Osoby, które logowały się: ");

            }
        }


        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path2))
        {
            string namesurname = Console.ReadLine();
            sw.WriteLine(namesurname);

        }
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path2))
        {
            string s = "";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
```

After couple hours i made something like this....
Can someone tell me next hint?

```css
class Person
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class FileExample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (true)
            {
                string choice = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case "Add":
                        break;
                    case "Update":
                        break;
                    case "Remove":
                        break;
                    case "Exit":
                        return;
                }
            }
        }

        static List<Person> LoadList()
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText("persons.txt");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                return new List<Person>() { };
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person[]>(text).ToList();
        }
        static void SaveList(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("persons.txt", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons.ToArray()));
        }
        static void AddPerson(List<Person> list, Person newPerson)
        {
            list.Add(newPerson);
        }
        static void RemovePerson(List<Person> list, int personId)
        {
            var foundPerson = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == personId);
            if (foundPerson != null)
                list.Remove(foundPerson);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this: https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline

Just create multiple verbs like: list, add, remove, change, makeFun etc and instead handle them in one process, just call EXE from command line with different operations